# abstracting handlebars templates into external files w/o AJAX

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is there any way to load handlebars templates more simply? Seems like an easy thing to be able to do. If I have the following code for `index.html`:

```
<body>
  <h1>From the index.html</h1>
  <div id="hbs"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
  <script id="test" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h2>This is from HBS</h2>
      <p>
        hbs generated this p tag!
      </p>
    </script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here's the code for the script to compile the template in `js/script.js`:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector("#test").innerHTML)
document.querySelector("#hbs").innerHTML = template({})
```

This works fine,but  when I open the `index.html` I can see the header and `p` tag generated through the template. There has to be an easy way to abstract this template into a separate file!

Answer (score 3):

You can put your template in a hbs file :

template.hbs:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h2>This is from HBS</h2>
      <p>
        hbs generated this p tag!
      </p>
</script>
```

And then use ajax to get your file instead of a querySelector to get your html

```
$document.ready(function(){
   $.get( '/url/template.hbs', function( source ) {
      var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
      document.querySelector("#hbs").innerHTML = template({});
   }
});
```

Comment: right, thanks i was familiar with this way. Was thinking it should be easy to not have to leverage ajax. But I couldn't find it. thanks!

Comment: Could you please accept the question of it is ok for you. Thanks

Comment: its not an accurate answer to the question i asked, it is a solution, but not one to the question posed. Says w/o AJAX